# A diode connected in parallel with a resistor

Tags: resistors, diodes

Consider a diode and a resistor both connected in parallel with a battery and the diode is reverse biased , there is no current flowing through it therefore the voltage across it is 0 , will the current through the resistor also be 0 because the voltage across it is also 0 ?

Comment: Your question doesn't make any sense.  If a diode is reverse biased, of course it has a voltage across it; it can't be reverse biased otherwise...

Comment: If a diode is reverse-biased, there will be no current through it, but the voltage across it will be whatever the applied voltage is.

Comment: An open switch has a voltage across it.  That is the voltage that makes the switched thing go if you close the switch.

Comment: This configuration is typical for a battery charger.

Answer (score 1):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fYoEQJ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. A resistor, a diode and an open circuit connected in parallel with a battery.*

> Consider a diode and a resistor both connected in parallel with a battery and the diode is reverse biased , there is no current flowing through it therefore the voltage across it is 0 ...

Consider a diode and a resistor both connected in parallel with a battery and the diode is reverse biased , there is no current flowing through it therefore the voltage across it is the battery voltage.

> Will the current through the resistor also be 0 because the voltage across it is also 0?

The current through the resistor will be given by Ohm's Law because the voltage across it is also the battery voltage.

Note that there is no current flowing through the open circuit either. What do you think the voltage will be there?

Answer (score 0):

Look at the I-V characteristic of a typical PN junction diode. When the diode is revered biased the diode is off and no current (except for a very small leakage current) will go through the diode.

[image]

In this case, the cathode is more positive than the anode. The reverse biased voltage can be hundreds of volts depending on the type of diode.

> there is no current flowing through it therefore the voltage across it is 0

The maximum reverse biased voltage that you can apply across the diode is known as the *breakdown voltage* (see the above image). You should look at the datasheet to determine this quantity. For zener diodes it can be as low as 1 or 2 volts. If a breakdown happens the diode will be short and it will allow current to flow. So no it can't be answered if we don't know the battery voltage and the diode used in the circuit.

> Consider a diode and a resistor both connected in parallel with a battery

A battery that is in parallel with a resistor sets a constant voltage across it. Then Ohm's Law tells you that a current of V/R will flow through it (no matter the rest of the circuit).